# Nginx, NodeJs, Express; CSS not found

Tags: css, node.js, nginx

From the research I've done I can see you need to edit a file in nginx and change a location so static files can be served but I don't quite understand how to do this so my css cannot be found, I got the file open and it looks like this:
[Nginx config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7nJI.png).
I don't really know what to do from here as the other similar questions seem to have very specific or complicated answers.

My html to link the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
```

my node server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/templates/index.html'));
});


app.listen(8080);
```

My folder layout:
[folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cxn6.png)

Comment: Are you trying to serve your CSS file with nginx or with your Express server?

Comment: In your folder layout screenshot, `static\css` looks like one name rather than a folder named `static` that contains another folder named `css`.

Comment: Trying to serve css with express in the ```app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
``` but it only works on localhost not on nginx server. Also static\css is just vscode shortening empty folders, it is two folders.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the right directory structure on the hosting then.  This shouldn't have anything at all to do with nginx unless you've got some conflicting rules in nginx that are stealing the URL and not letting it through to your Express server.

Comment: Try putting this before your `express.static()` line of code to debug.  `app.use("/css", (req, res, next) => { console.log("got /css", req.url); next();});` and see if you get that `console.log()` or not.  If not, then nginx is stealing the URL and not letting it through to express.  If so, then something is wrong with the directory structure of the `express.static()` line.

Comment: I've tried the structure using localhost on my machine, not on server and it seems to work perfectly but on server it wont work at all

Comment: Did you try the logging middleware on the hosted server I asked you to try?  If so, what results did you get?

Comment: I'm currently trying a different way of setting up the server to see if I can fix this issue, once i've added the node and express code ill add that line in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this applies to every situation, however:
When using an ubuntu server to host a nodejs / express website, nginx isn't needed at all. Simply make the express server run on port 80, the web traffic port, disable ufw firewall to allow all traffic, set up cloudfare or any other ssl that allows http and https to act as a new firewall. Once the server is running on port 80 and your domain is set up correctly with the right nameservers etc, it should all be working an then optionally you can use pm2 to host mutliple things or still have access to server while website is running.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I just resolved it by restructuring my folders.
Check the path in the error you see via dev tools and see if it matches your folder structure.

Another resolve might be in your nginx configuration. I added

> include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

in the server directive block, though the folder restructure is what fixed my problem.

Comment: I this could have potentially worked but I think I may have found a solution that works for express nodejs servers.